# Why gradle always downloads plugins in https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

Gradle provides offline mode to build with local cache which is friendly without internet access. But I found on my new project, gradle always tries to download plugins in https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/. No matter how many times I run the build, the next build still tries to download:

```
09:23:13.132 Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/gradle/plugin/com/ewerk/gradle/plugins/querydsl-plugin/1.0.6/querydsl-plugin-1.0.6.jar
```

here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl"
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
           url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.5.RELEASE"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.ewerk.gradle.plugins:querydsl-plugin:1.0.6"
    }

}
```

Is it possible to use cache instead?

Comment: This happens if you use the new plugins { } closure as well. There seems to be a separate code path for plugins that doesn't use the cache :(